# stop scan function every 10 sec then start again until something finish - angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hello guys im working with a [ionic native library](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central) who gimme some tools for bluetooth Connection and stuff, i need a little help with rxjs observables to make a function to run the bluetooth scanner when i enter to my view for 15 seconds then stop the function , retry after 2 second and run it again for 15 second till my process of bluetooth Connection is complete, these are my main functions that i need to make it works as explained:

```html
// here i want to start the scan for 15 seconds to search for a device //but some times it doesn't appear the first scan so i need to refresh //my view to find the device for that i want to "retry" the scan every // 15 seconds

this.ble.startScan([]).subscribe(
          foundDevice => { 
          if(foundDevice.name.includes('myDevice'){
            // here im going to connect
            connectToDevice(foundDevice);
          }
          
          }
   });
   
   
// when connect to device finish then stop the scan

connectToDevice(foundDevice){
this.ble.connect(foundDevice.id).subcribe(
  () => {
    // show some message
    myMessageFunction('yaaay, connected');
    /// stop the scan function
    this.ble.stopScan();
  }
)

}
```

i really dont have any clue how to make it works because i only know about subscribers.

thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `ble.startScan` do? Does it ever times out? Does it keep running infinitely until you stop it? Does it error at some point if nothing is found?

Comment: yeah, the ble.startScan never ends till you stop it by stopScan

Answer (score 1):

With some missing information, here's my take at it:

```
// lets build a wrapper to have the library wrapped as a reactive stream
const bluetoothScan$: Observable<Device> = defer(() => {
  return new Observable<Device>(observer => {
    const sub = bluetoothService.startScan().subscribe(observer);

    return () => {
      bluetoothService.stopScan();
      sub.unsubscribe;
    };
  });
});

const bluetoothScanPolling$: Observable<Device> = bluetoothScan$.pipe(
  timeout(15000),
  repeatWhen(() => timer(2000))
);

const deviceConnected$: Observable<Device> = bluetoothScanPolling$.pipe(
  filter(foundDevice => foundDevice.name.includes("myDevice")),
  switchMap(foundDevice => bluetoothService.connect(foundDevice.id)),
  take(1)
);

const displayMessageWhenDeviceConnected$: Observable<
  any
> = deviceConnected$.pipe(
  tap(device => console.log(`Device with ID ${device.id} is now connected`))
);
```

The `bluetoothScan$` lets us wrap the start scan into an observable from which when we unsubscribe to it, we automatically call the `stopScan`.

Then we can use `timeout` to stop after 15s and `repeatWhen` to resubscribe to the observable after 2s.

I hope it makes sense. Here's a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jxbphv but no running code it was just to play around with it